# simple mysql statement that I can not find

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Sorry didn't know what title to give to this question as it might get confusing.

My table has only two columns - userName1 and userName2
I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Friends` WHERE `userName1` = 'aName'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `Friends` WHERE `userName2` = 'aName'
```

The result of this sql statements brings me the rows that include '`aName`' in either `userName1` or `userName2`.
How to filter the result to show the OTHER entry only? avoid returning the column that contains 'aName'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
select userName2 from friends where userName1 = 'aName'
union
select userName1 from friends where userName2 = 'aName';
```

A method without `union`:

```
select distinct (case when userName1 = 'aName' then userName2 else userName1 end)
from friends
where 'aName' in (userName1, userName2);
```

Comment: I think the where clause should be   WHERE (userName1 =  'aName' OR  userName2 =  'aName' )

Comment: totally works thank you. trying to covert that to php now

Comment: any idea how will I return user1Image OR user2Image together with username1 or userName2? something like then (userName2,userImage2) or for the other case (userName1,userImage1)

Comment: @cmario . . . That sounds like something that should be asked in another question rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this :

```
SELECT userName2 as 'name' FROM Friends WHERE userName1 = 'aName'
UNION
SELECT userName1 as 'name' FROM Friends WHERE userName2 = 'aName'
```

You might also require that they can't be both equal to 'aName'

```
SELECT userName2 as 'name' FROM Friends WHERE userName1 = 'aName' and userName2 != 'aName'
UNION
SELECT userName1 as 'name' FROM Friends WHERE userName2 = 'aName' and userName1 != 'aName'
```

(...which could be improved)

Comment: Oops I was a bit late

Answer (score -2):

IF this is the case you can use INNER JOIN

```
  SELECT *
    FROM `Friends` f
   INNER JOIN `Friends` f1
    ON f.userName1 = f1.userName2
```

Comment: This query is incomplete. You need validate `'aName'` also the friend can be in `userName1` or `userName2`.  And you need return a single column no `*`

Comment: This simply doesn't answer the question.

Comment: UNION  will do the same function as INNER JOIN  and when you filter based on the Same column. The result set should come the same.

Comment: @Maverick No UNION doesn't the same than INNER JOIN. Furthermore the OP requested one field per row where your `select` returns 4,  you will get all the combinations of records, you suppose the the only way f.userName1 = f1.userName2 is when they are equal to 'aName' which is not necessarily the case....